# Export to Excel not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I am generating excel file and it working fine in local host but not working in IIS.I have a model pop up from where i open pop up window using `window.open` method where following code is written to generate excel file.

```
 public void GenerateExcelFile(DataTable dt)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    string filename = "abc.xls";
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
    gv.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

}
```

Please help me to resolve issue.

Comment: Check for iis mime types and if you don't have add vnd.ms-excel. What's your erroneous code in the browser?

Comment: what error are you facing while working with IIS?

Comment: download dialog box not appear for excel file.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the dialog process. Could you post the relevant code ? What should the dialog contain ? What browser are you using ?

Comment: I am using IE8.same code working fine when run in local host.But not working while run in IIS.I call this method in page load.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we where trying to do this, we ended up using this lovely little library: [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

It made the whole process of making our sheets very easy, clean and efficient. Hopefully it will provide a solution to your problem.